# Unable to send request body in Http GET method on angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, http, get, angular10

I want to send empty object in http get request body to work api on angular 10. Our api server need empty request body object in GET request.

I want like this
{
method: 'get',
url: 'http://domain.api.com/api/method?param1=value1',
body: {
key:value
}
}

Note: I dont want to use POST method for send request body.

Comment: An "empty body" would be `{}`. Why are you trying to send `{ key:value }`?

Comment: You should read the answers here about sending a `body` with a `GET` request: https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/1024832

Comment: Yes empty body {} , { key:value } it was example.

Comment: You should read the answers here about sending a body with a GET request: stackoverflow.com/a/983458/1024832 

>> i read this and i didnt understood , how can i implement it on angular 10 can you provide me sample code?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Post for a payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request.

You can read more detail [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231)